# How Ethereum devs maintains it's api versions?

Tags: go-ethereum, api-design

I'd like to know is there any versioning or maintaining rules about APIs in Ethereum.

In the dev world, "backward compatibility" is really important especially in APIs.

There are many APIs in Ethereum and those should be treated carefully to keep backward compatibility.
Anyway, is there anyone who knows how Ethereum maintains those things?

From what I've seen so far

- There is no special mechanism about maintaining API versions to keep backward compatibility.
- But There are two repos to discuss dev-related issues with stake holders(Dapp developers, etc...)

  - https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs
  - https://github.com/ethereum/pm

If anyone who knows about this, please let me know.
Thanks all :)